# Logic behind Browser loading indicator

Tags: jquery, web-applications, browser

I have a web app where I make a bunch of ajax calls when the page is loaded. I was expecting the browser would drop the loading indicator as soon as the page was loaded and the JS, CSS files were downloaded. But it keeps on showing the loading indicator till all ajax calls have returned.

But if I wait for "sometime" before making the ajax calls the browser does drop the loading indicator. The amount of time I have to wait is not fixed. On localhost 200ms is enough but on server with browser cache cleared, around 2secs is required. Is it the time required for all js and css files to be downloaded ?

Does anyone know the logic behind this. When should I make the ajax calls on page load so that browser's loading indicator does not wait till all ajax calls have returned ?

Comment: Do you have images on the page? If using Firebug/Chrome check "Network" tab - it will show what exactly is loading.